# my bit level add function always sets the first bit to 0

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build bit level addition for my emulator
It works for the most part, but the first bit of my accumulator register always gets set to 0, and I can't figure out why?

```
int main()
{
    MCS6502 processor;
    char mem1 = 0b00000001;
    char mem2 = 0b00000001;
    char mem3 = 0b00000000;

    processor.LDA(mem1); //loads memory into accumulator
    processor.ADC(mem2); //adds the inputed address to the accumulator
    processor.STA(mem3); //stores the accumulator in memory

    std::cout << +mem3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


void MCS6502::LDA(const char &address)
{
    registers[0] = address; //loads Accumulator
}

void MCS6502::STA(char &address)
{
    address = registers[0]; //stores Accumulator
}

void MCS6502::ADC(const char &address)
{
    char carry = 0b00000000;

    if (flags[0] == true)
    {
        carry = 0b00000001;
    }

    char accumulator_bit_array[7];
    char address_bit_array[7];
    char result_bit_array[7];

    ByteToBitArray(accumulator_bit_array, registers[0]);

    std::cout << "accum bit after the function has ran " << +accumulator_bit_array[0] << std::endl;

    ByteToBitArray(address_bit_array, address);

    std::cout << "address bit after the function has ran " << +address_bit_array[0] << std::endl;


    int i = 0;

    while (i < 8)
    {
        std::cout << "counter "<< i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Accumulator bit in = " << +accumulator_bit_array[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Address bit in = " << +address_bit_array[i] << std::endl;
        result_bit_array[i] = BitwiseAdd(accumulator_bit_array[i], address_bit_array[i], carry);
        std::cout << "Bitwise Add restult = " << +result_bit_array[i] << std::endl;
        i++;
    }

    registers[0] = BitArrayToByte(result_bit_array);

    if (carry == 0b00000001)
    {
        flags[0] = true;
    }

    if (carry == 0b00000000)
    {
        flags[0] = false;
    }
}


char BitwiseAdd(const char &bit1, const char &bit2, char &carry)
{
    char xor_ = bit1 ^ bit2;
    char ret = carry ^ xor_;
    carry = (carry & xor_) | (bit1 & bit2);
    return ret;
}

void ByteToBitArray(char bit_array[], const char &byte)
{
    std::cout << "Byte inside array function before conversion " << +byte << std::endl;

    bit_array[0] = byte & 0b00000001;
    bit_array[1] = byte & 0b00000010;
    bit_array[2] = byte & 0b00000100;
    bit_array[3] = byte & 0b00001000;
    bit_array[4] = byte & 0b00010000;
    bit_array[5] = byte & 0b00100000;
    bit_array[6] = byte & 0b01000000;
    bit_array[7] = byte & 0b10000000;

    bit_array[1] = bit_array[1] >> 1;
    bit_array[2] = bit_array[2] >> 2;
    bit_array[3] = bit_array[3] >> 3;
    bit_array[4] = bit_array[4] >> 4;
    bit_array[5] = bit_array[5] >> 5;
    bit_array[6] = bit_array[6] >> 6;
    bit_array[7] = bit_array[7] >> 7;

    std::cout << "Bit inside array function after conversion " << +bit_array[0] << std::endl;
}

char BitArrayToByte(char bit_array[])
{
    char byte = 0b00000000;

    bit_array[1] = bit_array[1] << 1;
    bit_array[2] = bit_array[2] << 2;
    bit_array[3] = bit_array[3] << 3;
    bit_array[4] = bit_array[4] << 4;
    bit_array[5] = bit_array[5] << 5;
    bit_array[6] = bit_array[6] << 6;
    bit_array[7] = bit_array[7] << 7;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 8)
    {
        byte = byte | bit_array[i];
        i++;
    }

    return byte;
}
```

My output when I run this is:

```
Byte inside array function before conversion 1
Bit inside array function after conversion 1
accum bit after the function has ran 1
Byte inside array function before conversion 1
Bit inside array function after conversion 1
address bit after the function has ran 1
counter 0
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 1
Bitwise Add restult = 1
counter 1
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
counter 2
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
counter 3
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
counter 4
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
counter 5
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
counter 6
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
counter 7
Accumulator bit in = 0
Address bit in = 0
Bitwise Add restult = 0
1
```

It should be 2, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3 arrays in `ADC` have 7 elements in them but the functions you pass them to expect 8.  This results in undefined behavior, which is showing here as overwriting the first byte of the next array.

Comment: Don't they have 8 because 0 is included as an index?

Comment: It worked, but I don't understand why? Because the other 8 bits fit into the array just fine, it was only the accumulator that didn't want to fit?

Comment: @Maurice The size in an array declaration is the number of elements in the array, which are indexed from 0..N-1.  Your arrays are declared with 7 elements, which will be indexed from 0..6.  Accessing element 7 will access outside the array, and the case of the accumulator _might_ have referred to the same memory location as the first element of `address_bit_array` (depending on how your compiler lays out the local variables).

Comment: Oh wow. I've been screwing myself over for awhile now.. Thanks for the info.